# Python--Using xlrd to obtain column heading and using a loop to create variables with column heading

Tags: python, xlrd

Let's say that I have an Excel file that has test IDs (both strings and numbers--I don't name them myself...) and results at different increments during the test (the test is conducted at specific incrments):

```
Inc. SV-101 GB-B1A 67.5
1    300    226    547    
2    363    344    600
3    461    444    615
.    .      .      .
.    .      .      .
.    .      .      .
10   421    444    625
```

I'd like to open the file using xlrd.  Then, I'd like to create a loop which creates a list using the names of the tests.  For example:

```
testID_SV-101 = ([300, 363, 461, ..., 421])
testID_GB-B1B = ([226, 344, 444, ..., 444])
testID_67.5 = ([547, 600, 615, ..., 625])
```

My ultimate goal is using the results from the tests and calculate, say, the slope from increment 4 to 9 and then plot the results.  Speaking of which, is this the best way to accomplish my final goal?

I've figured out (with lots of help) how to do this using gnuplot, but I foresee that it won't be able to everything that I need it to do so I decided to start learning Python.

Answer (score 0):

Your data lends itself for python's numeric library `numpy` (but you could use `Pandas` too, but that's based on `numpy` anyway). For plotting, you should look into e.g. [`matplotlib`](http://matplotlib.org/).

What you want is to store each row in your sheet as a record in a structured array. That's because each row is a logical group of things related to one and the same thing (e.g. a measurement result). Later, you can access all of them by the names given in the first row, which are used to identify each record's meaning. Below is the code that will work.

```
>>> import xlrd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> 
>>> wb = xlrd.open_workbook('sto.xls')
>>> sheet = wb.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
>>> headers = [str(cell.value) for cell in sheet.row(0)]  # extra conversion to string required for later use in record array header
>>> headers
['Inc.', 'SV-101', 'GB-B1A', '67.5']
>>> arr = []
>>> for rowind in range(sheet.nrows)[1:]:
...     arr.append([ cell.value for cell in sheet.row(rowind)])
... 
>>> arr
[[1.0, 300.0, 226.0, 547.0], [2.0, 363.0, 344.0, 600.0], [3.0, 461.0, 444.0, 615.0]]
>>> data = np.rec.fromrecords(arr, names=headers)
>>> data
rec.array([(1.0, 300.0, 226.0, 547.0), (2.0, 363.0, 344.0, 600.0),
       (3.0, 461.0, 444.0, 615.0)], 
      dtype=[('Inc.', '<f8'), ('SV-101', '<f8'), ('GB-B1A', '<f8'), ('67.5', '<f8')])
>>> data['SV-101']  # You can access columns by their name
array([ 300.,  363.,  461.])
>>> data['67.5']  # bit of a strange header name
array([ 547.,  600.,  615.])
>>> # If you want to plot e.g. the 3rd column vs the 2nd, do this:
>>> plt.plot(data['SV-101'], data['GB-B1A'])
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x2af3c90>]
>>> plt.show()
```

As for determining the "slope" between records 4 and 9, well that part of your question is a bit unclear. You could mean the difference between each consecutive record (and then for each column), in which case you'll get 5 values (in my example only 2):

```
>>> np.diff(data['SV-101'])
array([ 63.,  98.])
```

Or you could want merely the tangential slope between those two points, in which case you would take the values you're interested in at those points (e.g. 'GB-B1A') and divide by the difference of the corresponding independant variables (e.g. 'SV-101'):

```
>>> (data['GB-B1A'][2] - data['GB-B1A'][0])/(data['SV-101'][2] - data['SV-101'][0])
1.3540372670807452
```

By the way, you cannot have python variables with names such as `testID_SV-101` (because the dash is not [allowed in an identifier](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers)) or `testID_67.5` (because the dot has a different meaning).

Comment: `TypeError: 'Row' object is not iterable`

Comment: @Cerin: Not a very useful description of your error (at which line does it occur), as *xlrd* [has no Row class](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/blob/master/xlrd/sheet.py#L466) (Sheet, yes, Row no). Are you even using xlrd? If you have an issue, ask a question rather than downvoting and giving an incomplete description of your problem in the comments.

Comment: @Cerin any feedback? It would help if you could specify where that error occurs so that others don't necessarily think there's anything wrong with the above lines, which you'll find over many blogs and tutorials.

Comment: I was operating on a sheet copied by `xlutils.copy.copy()`. Apparently, despite the name, it doesn't produce an instance of the same class type, and therefore is missing most of  the common attributes and iterators in a normal sheet instance.